# RestSharp serialization not serializing class name correctly

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

RestSharp doesn't seem to be paying attention to the "SerializeAs" attribute that I've decorated one of my class names with:

**Person**

```
[Serializable, SerializeAs(Name = "person")]
public class Person
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "first-name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "contact-data")]
    public ContactData ContactData { get; set; }
}
```

**ContactData**

```
public class ContactData
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "email-addresses")]
    public List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

**EmailAddress**

```
[SerializeAs(Name = "email-address")]
public class EmailAddress
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the following code to serialize the XML:

```
var request = new RestRequest("people/{id}.xml", Method.PUT);
request.AddParameter("id", person.Id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer();
request.AddBody(person);
```

However, the resulting XML looks like this:

```
<person>
    <first-name>Scott</first-name> 
    <contact-data>
        <email-adresses>
            <EmailAddress>
                <address>my@email.com</address> 
                <location>Work</location> 
             </EmailAddress>
        </email-adresses>
    </contact-data>
</person>
```

You can see that the `<EmailAddress>` element appears to be ignoring the `SerializeAs` attribute and is not serialized to "email-address" as I would expect it to be while all of the others work just fine. Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: do you not need an attribute above this class `public class ContactData`..? `[SerializeAs(Name = "email-addresseses")]`

Comment: No, ContactData serializes properly to "contact-data" as the ContactData property in the Person class is decorated with the SerializeAs attribute. It seems to be just EmailAddress that has the issue.

Comment: could you try naming it something else or remove the `-` to see if it's a naming conflict.. I have seen something like this before but off hand can't remember the reference of the site I used to fix the same issue

Comment: Tried renaming it to "test" - no dice. Still serializes to "EmailAddress".

Comment: I just noticed something can you change or try this instead 
`request.XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));`

Comment: also you can try using this attribute as well on the ContractData `[KnownType(typeof(Person))]`

Comment: KnownType didn't work....XmlSerializer doesn't have an overload that takes a Type parameter. I appreciate the suggestions though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After poking around the RestSharp source, I realized this is a bug in the XmlSerializer built into RestSharp. I've fixed it and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/361).